# PDF creation with rails and ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, pdf-generation, ember-data, prawn

I've been researching the best way to generate a feature rich, well-designed PDF based on the analytics platform we provide to our current clients. Our stack is ember.js, ember-data, and ruby on rails. We use D3.js and rickshaw to provide advanced graphing and insight, and would like to incorporate this into our pdf generation as much as possible. After initial research, it seems like prawn has been the most highly recommended, but seems far too basic for our design purposes. Does anyone have any recommendations for something that could help here?

Comment: maybe try https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit

Comment: or read that http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/52-serverside-generated-charts

Answer (score 0):

I would use the addin ember-js-pdf.
Download the data from the server and use to define the nessary elements/steps of the pdf and then create the PDF using the addin.

Have a look at https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-js-pdf for the details.